# Close Jquery Modal Dialog box when click outside

Tags: popup

my modal jquery box works fine, but how can i add the option to
close the popup when i click outside of the box?

here is my code:

```
<script>    
            $(function() {
             $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
              width: 900,
              height: 600,

              show: {
               effect: "blind",
               duration: 1000
              },

              hide: {
               effect: "explode",
               duration: 1200
              },

              open: function(event, ui){
               //setTimeout("$('#dialog').dialog('close')",10000);
               $('.ui-widget-overlay').live('click', function() {
                     $('#dialog').dialog( "close" );
                });
              }

             });
            });
        </script>
```

**Updated**

Thanks for your help, but it doesnt work, i added your idea like this:

```
<script>    
        $(function() {
         $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
          width: 900,
          height: 600,

          show: {
           effect: "blind",
           duration: 200
          },

          hide: {
           effect: "explode",
           duration: 1300
          },

          open: function(event, ui){
           //setTimeout("$('#dialog').dialog('close')",10000);
           $('.ui-widget-overlay').live('click', function() {
                 $('#dialog').dialog( "close" );
            });

           $( "#dialog" ).bind('clickoutside',function(){
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog('close');
            });

          }


         });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I update your answer in your actual question and recommend to delete the answer. so site will be nit and clean

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
$( "#dialog" ).bind('clickoutside',function(){
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog('close');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Keith Ratner's solution described [here](http://www.keithratner.com/close-jquery-ui-dialog-by-clicking-outside/) works well.

When specifying the dialog(s), add a distinctive class to identify all the dialogs you wish to be closeable on click outside:

```
dialogClass: "clickoncloseoutside",
```

Add the behaviour to the whole page to close all the open dialogs when clicked anywhere in the body:

```
$("body").on("click", "div.ui-widget-overlay:visible", function() {
    $(".ui-dialog.clickoncloseoutside:visible")
        .find(".ui-dialog-content")
        .dialog("close");
});
```